# Can you help me with this mistake to save a xml file in php?

Tags: php, html, xml, csv, xampp

this is the error I get in PHP. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WorldDataParser::saveXML() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/WME/save.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/WME/save.php on line 18`

I would like to save the XML but there is this error that I can't really do anything with?

What exactly does the error tell me?

My code:

WorldDataParser Class:

```
function saveXML($xml, $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $id => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($id)) {
                $id = "country";
            };

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $object = $xml->addChild($id);
                $this->saveXML($object, $value);
            } else {
                $id = strtr($id, " ", "_");
                $xml->addChild($id, $value);
            }
        }
        return $xml->asXML("world_data_v1.xml");
    }
```

saveXML.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

    require('world_data_parser.php');

    $worldDataParser = new WorldDataParser();

    $array = $worldDataParser->parseCSV("world_data_v1.csv");

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Countries></Countries>");
    $result = $worldDataParser->saveXML($xml, $array);
    $xml->asXML("world_data.xml");

    if($result){
        print ("XML Savestatus: erfogreich! ("); print_r($result); print (")");
    } else {
        print ("XML Savestatus: nicht erfogreich! ("); print_r($result); print (")");
    }

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to put `public function saveXML($xml, $array)` instead of `function saveXML($xml, $array)`

Comment: i got this error in vscode: `syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file`

Comment: Please include the complete code of `WorldDataParser`. Something is amiss.

Comment: i have a new error: `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(world_data_v1.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/WME/world_data_parser.php on line 40` The first error is solved. Can you help me with the new error?

Comment: @avydesign i mean in the `WorldDataParser` class. Not in `saveXML.php`

Answer (score 0):

This is the total code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <?php

    class WorldDataParser
    {
        public function parseCSV($csvFile)
        {
            if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                $head = fgetcsv($handle);
                while (!feof($handle)) {
                    $array[] = array_combine($head, fgetcsv($handle));
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
            return $array;
        }

        public function saveXML($xml, $array)
        {
            foreach ($array as $id => $value) {
                if (is_numeric($id)) {
                    $id = "country";
                };

                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $object = $xml->addChild($id);
                    $this->saveXML($object, $value);
                } else {
                    $id = strtr($id, " ", "_");
                    $xml->addChild($id, $value);
                }
            }
            return $xml->asXML("world_data_v1.xml");
        }

        public function printXML($xml, $xsl)
        {

            $domDocumentXSL = new DOMDocument();
            $domDocumentXSL->load($xsl);

            $domDocumentXML = new DOMDocument();
            $domDocumentXML->load($xml);

            $xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            $xsltProcessor->importStylesheet($domDocumentXSL);

            return $xsltProcessor->transformToXml($domDocumentXML);
        }
    }   

    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should edit your question if you want to add more details instead of answering it